# How to NSPredicate for a to-one relationship when using Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data with Song, Artist and Album entity.

Song have an optional one to one relationship 
artist to the Artist entity and album to Album entity 
Both entity has an inverse relationship to the Song entity.

Album have an optional one to one relationship 
artist to the Artist entity and an optional one to many relationship
songs to Song entity

Both entity has an inverse relationship to the Album entity.

Artist have an optional one to one relationship 
album to the Album entity and an optional one to many relationship
songs to Song entity 
Both entity has an inverse relationship to the Artist entity.

I would like to fetch distinct artist name and started to do this

```
NSArray *getAllArtistArray = [Song findBy:nil orderBy:@"songName asc"]; // fetch all songs in Song entity
```

then i loop them to find unique artist name

```
 for(Song *songItem in getAllArtistArray)
 {
        BOOL hasDuplicate = [[uniqueArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"artist.artistName", songItem.artist.artistName]] count] > 0;
        if (!hasDuplicate)//if uniqueArray found artistname, don add songItem
        {
            [uniqueArray addObject:songItem];
        }
  }
```

here is the problem :/

I need to find the Song and Album count of individual artist.

```
//fixed Indention
//this works for finding the song count of individual Artist but is this the right way ?
  -(int)searchSongItemCountInSongbasedOnArtist:(NSString *)searchStr //song count of artist
 {
     NSPredicate *getSearchPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"artist.artistName", searchStr];
     NSArray *countArray = [Song findBy:getSearchPred orderBy:@"artist.artistName asc"];        
     [self searchAlbumCountBasedOnArtist:searchStr andSongArray:countArray];

     return [countArray count];
 }
```

how to i find the album count of individual based on the artist name ?
MPMediaQuery can easily do it, how i can do it using NSPredicate with coredata ?

```
-(int)searchAlbumCountBasedOnArtist:(NSString *)searchStr andSongArray:(NSArray *)songArray
{
    MPMediaQuery *albumQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    NSArray *albumCollection = [albumQuery collections];
    [albumQuery addFilterPredicate: [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:searchStr
                                      forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]];
    return [albumCollection  count];
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Album

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Artist, Song;

@interface Album : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * albumID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * albumTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * albumTitleEN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *artists;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;
@end

@interface Album (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addArtistsObject:(Artist *)value;
- (void)removeArtistsObject:(Artist *)value;
- (void)addArtists:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeArtists:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addSongsObject:(Song *)value;
- (void)removeSongsObject:(Song *)value;
- (void)addSongs:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSongs:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Song

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Album, Artist;

@interface Song : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * acousticness;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * danceability;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * deleted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * durationEN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * energy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * genre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * key;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * liveness;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * loudness;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * md5Hash;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mood;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * pID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * playbackDuration;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * serverID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * songName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * songNameEN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * songURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * speechiness;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tempo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * valance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Album *albums;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Artist *artists;

@end
```

Artist

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Album, Song;

@interface Artist : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * artistID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * artistIDEN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * artistName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * artistNameEN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *albums;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;
@end

@interface Artist (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addAlbumsObject:(Album *)value;
- (void)removeAlbumsObject:(Album *)value;
- (void)addAlbums:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeAlbums:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addSongsObject:(Song *)value;
- (void)removeSongsObject:(Song *)value;
- (void)addSongs:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSongs:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Any comments / answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let me point out that I have no knowledge of the library you are using (VPPCoreData or whatever) - I try and avoid anything that seems to make things simpler because invariably there is a tradeoff somewhere.

Secondly - trying to figure out the code where things get added and relationships get set.

`Songs` get created and the `album` is assigned with this code (note `albums` and `artists` are To-One relationships and should be renamed to singular `album` and `artist` to avoid confusion with a To-Many relationship)

```
song.albums = [self findOrCreateAlbumFromMediaItem:mediaItem];
song.artists = [self findOrCreateArtistFromMediaItem:mediaItem];
```

I assume that a song exists in only one `Album` and a song has but one `Artist`.

Now you don't set any relationships between the `Artist` and the `Album` which is why it always comes up ZERO.  And its probably better not to because you can get this relationship from the `artist.songs` relationship.

So you have two choices, 1) determine the albums based on the songs that are related to the artist and don't maintain a artist.albums or albums.artists relationship, or 2) set the album.artists relationship yourself and use that.

For 1) You need to do this

```
// Get the array of Albums
NSArray *list = [artist.songs valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.album"];
NSLog(@" album count is %d", list.count);
for (Album *album in list) {
    NSLog(@" album is %@", album.albumTitle);
}
```

For 2) it means maintain duplicate information and the risk that something gets out of sync, but it could be easier to simply set the relationship when getting the album and artist.  If anything changes you have to change the relationships too.

```
song.album = [self findOrCreateAlbumFromMediaItem:mediaItem];
song.artist = [self findOrCreateArtistFromMediaItem:mediaItem];

NSMutableSet *albumArtists = [song.album mutableSetValueForKey:@"artists"];
[albumArtists addObject:song.artist];
```

You could add a read only property to the Artist object like this

in `Artist.h`

```
@property (readonly) NSArray *albumList;
```

in `Artists.m`

```
- (NSArray *)albumList {
    return [artist.songs valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.album"];
}
```

Then you can just do the following to get the count

```
albumCount = [[artist albumList] count];
```

or perhaps dot notation will work

```
albumCount = artist.albumList.count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the artist and then use `artist.albums.count`.

This assumes you have a To-Many relationship between `Artist` and `Album` called `albums` and another between `Artists` and `Song` called `songs`.

Similarly you could use `artist.songs.count` to get the number of songs

Here is a generic method to fetch an array of entities

```
- (NSArray *)getData:(NSString*)entityName sortField:(NSString*)sortKey predicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    NSLog(@"getData called");

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error can't continue with null managedObjectContext");
        return nil;
    }
    if (entityName == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error can't continue with null entityName");
        return nil;
    }
    if (sortKey == nil) {  // if its not set then just set it as follows...
        NSLog(@"Error can't continue with null sortField");
        return nil;
    }
    NSLog(@" entity is %@", entityName);

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    if (entity == nil) {
        NSLog(@"  error finding entity %@ in class %@", entityName, [self class]);
        return nil;
    }

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    if (predicate)
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (!result) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        return nil;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then to get the album and song counts

```
- (void)listAllMethod {

   NSArray *artists = [self getData:@"Artists" sortField:@"artistName" predicate:nil managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext;

   for (Artist *artist in artists) {
      NSLog(@" artist is %@", artist.artistName);
      NSLog(@"  album count is %d", [artist.albums.count intValue]);
      NSLog(@"  song count is %d", [artist.songs.count intValue]);
      for (Album *album in artist.albums)
         NSLog(@"     album is %@", album.albumTitle);
      for (Song *song in artist.songs)
         NSLog(@"     song is %@", song.songName);

   }

   NSArray *albums = [self getData:@"Albums" sortField:@"albumTitle" predicate:nil managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext;

   for (Album *album in albums) {
      NSLog(@" album is %@", album.albumTitle);
      NSLog(@"  artist count is %d", [album.artists.count intValue]);
      for (Artist *artist in albums.artists)
         NSLog(@"     artist is %@", artist.artistName);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
NSLog(@"  album count is %d", [artist.albums.count intValue]); does not give me back the album count.

edited question with entity screenshots

Comment: what does it give you ?
What does this give you `NSLog(@" albums are %@", artist.albums);` ?

Comment: Show the code you are using to create the Artist, Songs and Albums.

Comment: artist is Joe Hisaishi
album count is 0
song count is 4

Comment: yes, song count is correct, album count is zero. Album should be at least 1

Comment: Well if 'NSLog(@" albums are %@", artist.albums);' is not listing the albums then the album is not being correctly linked to the Artist.  Try listing all the albums and 'NSLog(@" artists are %@", album.artists);' for each album.

Comment: Hi Duncan,

got this nslog

 album artists Relationship 'artists' fault on managed object (0x16f11650) <Album: 0x16f11650> (entity: Album; id: 0x16e00460 <x-coredata://AB1752A0-51BA-4685-86D7-3CC2F5E7B9D5/Album/p149> ; data: {
    albumID = "-6606984736707850324";
    albumTitle = "Unknown Album";
    albumTitleEN = nil;
    artists = "<relationship fault: 0x16f12430 'artists'>";
    songs = "<relationship fault: 0x16f13fb0 'songs'>";
})

Comment: Try iterating over the arrays as per the modified code I just posted in my answer to list all albums and artists.  The faults you see have special meaning for Core Data, just means the object is not retrieved from the store.  Iterating over them objects will fetch whatever is there.

Comment: Hi Duncan, 

Thank you very much for all your helpful reply, as i still quite new on core data relationships. the edited answers still did not provide the album count, am i missing something on the code or the core data relationship linking ?

NSLog Result
artist is The Jackson 5
album count is 0
song count is 1
song is ABC
artist is Enya
album count is 0
song count is 2
song is Anywhere Is
song is Orinoco Flow
artist is Daniel Powter
album count is 0
song count is 1
song is Bad Day

Comment: i have a copy of my code here.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/418769/MediaService.m

Comment: OK I'll have a look, if the code is working for the song count it should be working for the album count so I guess something else must be going wrong.  Will get back to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44922/discussion-between-duncan-groenewald-and-desmond)